# 1999 Buick Century has no power (no lights, won't crank, no remote door unlock)

Tags: buick, century

The other day I came out after work to go home, put the key in the ignition and 
tried to start it up. Nothing, like the car had no power. No lights, nothing. After 
a few minutes the car suddenly came to life and started up. This morning I 
went outside to drive to work, the car started up fine. I went to the store and 
had the issue trying to start it back up. It finally started up like it had the 
previous time. Then while on my way to work, the dashboard started going 
crazy. I am talking about the dials going back and forth, lights going on and off, 
but the car kept running and I made it to work. As soon as I pulled in to my 
parking spot I turned off the car and tried to start it again... nothing. It's like the 
car has just lost power. What is going on?

Comment: Hi Jeffrey and welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Had this, or at least very similar, once before.

It was a broken internal link in the battery : worked fine then hit a bump and fails ...

Get the battery checked, but intermittant faults like that are hard to replicate...

If you can borrow a second battery then try it...

Comment: Thank you! I ended up replacing the battery and the issues are gone. It starts up a lot more easily now, too. Go figure.